# ./stack.sh failed while installing Openstack

Tags: python, linux, pip, openstack, devstack

I am not able to install OpenStack. I executed the script stack.sh and there was Error on exit. I looked at the log, the error is during the execution of the command: sudo -H -E python /home/sagar/devstack/files/get-pip.py :

This is the error during the execution of the below command:

sudo -H -E python /home/sagar/devstack/files/get-pip.py 
Collecting pip 
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip 
       No distributions at all found for pip 
++ err_trap 
++ local r=1

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. The system date was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the script and append `--allow-unverified`

ie `pip install package_name==version --allow-unverified package_name`

Comment: which script to edit? There is nothing like pip install in whole directory